# Use arraylist info in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, parsing, arraylist

I have a web service client which returns an object arraylist and two other values, this is the class that the web-service returns:

```
public class RespuestaObtenerLimites {

private int cdgError;
private String descError;
private ArrayList<Limite> listaLimites;

public int getCdgError() {
    return cdgError;
}
public void setCdgError(int cdgError) {
    this.cdgError = cdgError;
}
public String getDescError() {
    return descError;
}
public void setDescError(String descError) {
    this.descError = descError;
}
public ArrayList<Limite> getListaLimites() {
    return listaLimites;
}
public void setListaLimites(ArrayList<Limite> listaLimites) {
    this.listaLimites = listaLimites;
}
```

I call this service through an action in a web proyect and would like to use the values stored in the arraylist in javascript. How can i do this?

I have seen plenty of help to change the arraylist to json in java, but i would rather not change any code on the java end. Is there any way to parse the list directly in javascript?

Thank you for your help....

```
function consultarLimites(_paisId,_zonaId,_regionId,_tiendaId,tipoLimite){
invocarJSONServiceAction('consultaLimites', {
    paisId: _paisId,
    zonaId: _zonaId,
    regionId: _regionId,
    tiendaId: _tiendaId,
    tipoLimite: _tipoLimite
}, 'consultaLimitesDatos', null, null);

rhHc_datosTiendas=function(data){
    if (data.resultado.cdgError=="0"){

        tiendasEditadas = new Array();

        columnasHeaderUsuarios = new Array();
        datosUsuariosTabla = new Array();
```

This is the method with which i call the client action:

```
public ServiceResult consultaLimites(){

    PeticionObtenerLimites _peticion = new PeticionObtenerLimites();
    RespuestaObtenerLimites _respuesta = new RespuestaObtenerLimites();

    try{

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        DatosSession datosSession = new DatosSession();
        datosSession = (DatosSession)session.getAttribute("netoSession");

        _peticion = new PeticionObtenerLimites();
        Long l = datosSession.getPaisId();
        _peticion.setPaisId(l.intValue());
        _peticion.setZonaId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("zonaId")));
        _peticion.setRegionId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("regionId")));
        _peticion.setTiendaId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tiendaId")));
        _peticion.setTipoLimite(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tipoLimite")));

        ObtieneLimites service = new ObtieneLimitesImpl(servurl);

        _respuesta = service.obtenerLimitesCaja(_peticion);
        boolean vacia = false;

        if (_respuesta.getListaLimites()== null || _respuesta.getListaLimites().size() == 0)
            vacia = true;

        return new ServiceResult(false, vacia, null, _respuesta);
    }catch (AxisFault af) {
        Logeo.logearExcepcion(af, "Error al invocar al WebService");
        af.printStackTrace();
        return new ServiceResult(true, true, "wserr", null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            Logeo.logearExcepcion(e, "Error generico");
            return new ServiceResult(true, true, "generr", null);
}

}
```

it seems easy enough to access the non list fields the response gives, like this:

```
data.resultado.cdgError
```

however, i simply don't know how to access that list! and everything i've tried returns errors (just doesn't work, i don't know what errors...)

Comment: Please, read about how/what to ask in the help section of this site. You're not telling us (in a clear way) what results you've gotten, what you expected to see, and nor are you giving us the data/info required to replicate the issue. BTW: Java and JavaScript have about as much in common as a cat and a caterpillar, so `data` is of the type: `Object`... just like a funtion is an instance of `Object`, or an array is an instance of `Object`... And avoid `new` in JS, especially `new Array`, use the literal `[]` instead)...

Comment: I have expanded my question, i apologize if i was not clear